# How to make python update or refresh??? (wxpython)

Tags: python, wxpython, refresh, reload

Where and how can I make it update or refresh????

if I push the button of bottom(button1, button2, button3), I want to make changes contexts, pos etc.

but I don't know how. can you help me for a sec???

Here is the code:

```
import wx


class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "refresh&update", size=(900,600))

        self.count = 0

        if self.count == 0:
            self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self,  pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 100))
            self.text.AppendText('00000000')

            self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(self,  pos=(100, 100), size=(100, 100))
            self.text1.AppendText('00000000')

            self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self,  pos=(170, 250), size=(100, 100))
            self.text2.AppendText('00000000')

        if self.count == 1:
            self.text3 = wx.TextCtrl(self,  pos=(100, 50), size=(100, 100))
            self.text3.AppendText('1111111')

            buttonl = wx.Button(self, label="1111111", pos=(450,100), size=(100,100))
            button2 = wx.Button(self, label="1111111", pos=(250,100), size=(100,100))

        if self.count == 2:
            self.text6 = wx.TextCtrl(self,  pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 100))
            self.text6.AppendText('22222222')

            self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self,  pos=(100, 100), size=(100, 100))
            self.text.AppendText('22222222')

            button3 = wx.Button(self, label="22", pos=(250,170), size=(100,100))
            button4 = wx.Button(self, label="22", pos=(350,170), size=(100,100))



        button1 = wx.Button(self, label="count0", pos=(150,450), size=(200,100))
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB1)


        button2 = wx.Button(self, label="count1", pos=(400,450), size=(200,100))
        button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB2)


        button3 = wx.Button(self, label="count2", pos=(650,450), size=(200,100))
        button3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB3)



    def OnB1(self, event):
        self.count = 0

    def OnB2(self, event):
        self.count = 1

    def OnB3(self, event):
        self.count = 2


app = wx.App()
frame = mainFrame(None, id = -1).Show()
app.MainLoop()




    ############################# error////////////////////////////////////
                self.counts = [
                    [ #count =0
                        image=wx.Image(u"aaa.jpg",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY),
                        self.bitmap_1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(image.Rescale(350, 350)), (490,420)),
                        self.bitmap_1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick,
                    ],
                    [ #count = 1
                        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="취소", pos=(490,550), size=(300,150)),
                        button_cancel.SetFont(wx.Font(40, wx.ROMAN, wx.SLANT, wx.BOLD, 0, "")),
                    ],
                ]
##################################
```

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

def BoundButton(*args,**kwargs):
    callback = kwargs.pop("callback",lambda e:None)
    btn = wx.Button(*args,**kwargs)
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,callback)
    return btn

def hide_all(itm):
    if isinstance(itm,(list,tuple)):
        for i in itm:
            hide_all(i)
    else:
        itm.Hide()

def show_all(itm):
    if isinstance(itm,(list,tuple)):
        for i in itm:
            show_all(i)
    else:
        itm.Show()

class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "refresh&update", size=(900,600))

        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="B1", pos=(100,400), size=(100,150))
        button_cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB1)

        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="B2", pos=(300,400), size=(100,150))
        button_cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB2)

        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="B3", pos=(500,400), size=(100,150))
        button_cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB3)


        self.count = 0

        self.counts = [
            [ #count =0
                BoundButton(self, label="count=01", pos=(100,300), size=(100,100)),
                BoundButton(self, label="count=11", pos=(100,500), size=(100,100)),
            ],
            [ #count = 1
                BoundButton(self, label="count=12", pos=(250,500), size=(100,100)),
                BoundButton(self, label="count=22", pos=(250,500), size=(100,100)),
            ],
            [ #count = 2
                 wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,"{0:08d}".format(1),  pos=(100, 50), size=(50, 50)),
                 BoundButton(self, label="count23", pos=(350,600), size=(100,100)),
                 BoundButton(self, label="count21", pos=(350,600), size=(100,100)),
            ],
        ]
        self.updateFromCount()

    def OnB1(self,event):
        self.count = 0
        self.updateFromCount()
    def OnB2(self,event):
        self.count = 1
        self.updateFromCount()
    def OnB3(self,event):
        self.count = 2
        self.updateFromCount()
    def updateFromCount(self):
        hide_all(self.counts)
        show_all(self.counts[self.count])

a = wx.App(redirect=0)
f = mainFrame()
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

but in this array, I didn't find out how

```
self.counts = [
                    [ #count =0
                        image=wx.Image(u"aaa.jpg",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY),
                        self.bitmap_1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(image.Rescale(350, 350)), (490,420)),
                        self.bitmap_1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick,
                    ],
                    [ #count = 1
                        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="취소", pos=(490,550), size=(300,150)),
                        button_cancel.SetFont(wx.Font(40, wx.ROMAN, wx.SLANT, wx.BOLD, 0, "")),
                    ],
                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only changing the variable `count`. `__init__` is called *once*. No new text is appended changed or anything, only the variable count is changed. In your button listeners you need to add code to change the text.

In the `OnB*` functions:

```
def OnB1(self, event):
    self.count = 0
    self.text.SetLabel("%06d"%self.count)
```

Comment: or even easier `self.text.SetLabel("%06d"%self.count)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Yeah, maybe I shouldn't answer these questions given my lack of experience with wxWidgets. Lol. Thanks!

Comment: @JoranBeasley:@Bair: Thank you so much. I understand why it doesn't work. but I counln't find out right answer. How can I create the button1, button2, button3, button4?? following your OnB* code, It can only change the  text. I want to make button and unrelated text.SetLabel(OnB1 -> text.AppendText('1235535')).

Comment: what? I dont understand what you are asking for

Comment: @Joran Beasley : I mean how can I make it right or work. Is it impossible??? Can you teach me some code that can changes with several button.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for something like this

```
import wx

def BoundButton(*args,**kwargs):
    callback = kwargs.pop("callback",lambda e:None)
    btn = wx.Button(*args,**kwargs)
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,callback)
    return btn

def hide_all(itm):
    if isinstance(itm,(list,tuple)):
        for i in itm:
            hide_all(i)
    else:
        itm.Hide()

def show_all(itm):
    if isinstance(itm,(list,tuple)):
        for i in itm:
            show_all(i)
    else:
        itm.Show()

class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "refresh&update", size=(900,600))
        self.count = 0
        self.counts = [
            [ #count =0
                wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'{0:08d}'.format(0),  pos=(0, 0), size=(100, 100)),
                wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'{0:08d}'.format(0),  pos=(100, 100), size=(100, 100)),
                wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'{0:08d}'.format(0),  pos=(170, 250), size=(100, 100)),
                BoundButton(self, label="count0", pos=(150,450), size=(200,100),callback=self.OnB1),
                BoundButton(self, label="count1", pos=(400,450), size=(200,100),callback=self.OnB1),
                BoundButton(self, label="count2", pos=(650,450), size=(200,100),callback=self.OnB1),
            ],
            [ #count = 1
                 wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,"{0:08d}".format(1),  pos=(100, 50), size=(100, 100)),
                 BoundButton(self, label="1111111", pos=(450,100), size=(100,100),callback=self.OnB2),
                 BoundButton(self, label="1111111", pos=(250,100), size=(100,100),callback=self.OnB2),
            ],

        ]
        self.updateFromCount()
    def OnB1(self,e):
        self.Toggle(1)
    def OnB2(self,e):
        self.Toggle(0)
    def Toggle(self,i):
        self.count = i
        self.updateFromCount()
    def updateFromCount(self):
        hide_all(self.counts)
        for i in range(self.count+1):
            show_all(self.counts[i])

a = wx.App(redirect=0)
f = mainFrame()
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you SO much^^. your answer is very helpful to me. Can I ask one more thing? I tried to apply my code. but I have some error in self.counts[](There is error code bottom of my Question code).